# infrequent 504s at nginx when proxying to node/express app

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy

We have a typical nginx+nodejs setup with node v4.2.2 & nginx v1.9.7.2

Backend service app running on express/nodejs is deployed in clustered mode using [recluster module](https://github.com/doxout/recluster) with child processes (equal to #cores) forked that listen on same port. nginx is used as reverse proxy to backend.
Each such instance/box (4 core 8 gb) of nginx+nodejs is serving around 100 tps at load with 90th percentile of latency around 120ms.

Problem is that we get infrequent (1-2 times every 5 min) 504s on nginx access log and related error log shows

```
(110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream
```

As I understand, it would happen when nginx timedout establishing a connection with nodejs server but all the matrices show nodejs is healthy. Also, all the requests below and above this error have normal latency and just one off request gets stuck. There is no corresponding log entry at nodejs server means request never reached node server.

Relevant nginx config below.

```
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

events {
  worker_connections 2000;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 60;
}

upstream node {
 server 127.0.0.1:3000;
 keepalive 256;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name abc.com

 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Connection "";
 proxy_read_timeout 60;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://node;
 }
}
```

Output to ss -s is

```
Total: 747 (kernel 0)
TCP:   7400 (estab 481, closed 6890, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 
6890/0), ports 0
```

It shows high timewait sockets but we don't see any errors in syslog means operating system's limits are not reached.

I have tried tuning network and nginx primarily taking clues from [blog post](https://engineering.gosquared.com/optimising-nginx-node-js-and-networking-for-heavy-workloads) with no luck.
Need help in forum to get right direction to debug this. Let me know what more info I can provide.